# GA timeline of weather of Azure Maps

Tags: azure-maps

we are using Azure Maps Weather feature in a global website. Asking if any expected timeline from preview to GA of weather service, as SLA is also important to us.

Answer (score 1):

Timelines aren't publicly disclosed but there are plans to GA the weather services very soon. I don't believe there will be any changes to the service with the move to GA other than the preview label being removed, so using it now will be nearly identical to using it once it has moved to GA.

**Update**: The announcement was just made, weather services are now GA: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-maps-weather-services-are-now-generally-available/